# std::streambuf instantiation in bare metal C++

Tags: c++, g++

I'm trying to develop software for bare-metal platform using C++. I don't use exceptions, RTTI, and dynamic memory allocation. (Use "-fno-exceptions -fno-unwind-tables -fno-rtti -nostdlib" in my g++ flags).
I'd like to reuse std::streambuf functionality to read/write sequential data, so I defined my own stream buffer by inheriting from std::streambuf. As the result I receive unresolved references when compiling the application:

```
undefined reference to `std::basic_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >::basic_streambuf()'
undefined reference to `std::basic_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >::~basic_streambuf()'
undefined reference to `std::basic_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >::imbue(std::locale const&)'
undefined reference to `std::basic_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >::setbuf(char*, int)'
undefined reference to `std::basic_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >::seekoff(long long, std::_Ios_Seekdir, std::_Ios_Openmode)'
...
```

The question is: Is there any way to instantiate std::streambuf functions during my compilation as any other normal template without trying to use one in stdlib?

**Update:** I'm fully aware that -nostdlib takes away the whole runtime environment. That's my intention. I just want to reuse templated classes in STL and BOOST using only placement new. Even if compiler tries to generate calls to some functions such as "void operator delete(void*)", "void __cxa_pure_virtual()", or "__aeabi_atexit()", I can create empty stubs knowing that these function will never be called. The question is whether there is any way to force regular implicit instantiation (upon use) of the system header classes like any other templated one?

Comment: Using `-nostdlib` takes pretty much the entire runtime base out of the C++ language; even things like `new` and `delete` are likely to be unavailable without that (see http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/faq.html#faq.what_is_libsupcxx) Also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3714167/g-without-libstdc-can-it-be-done-a-very-configurable-lightweight-libstd has some references.

Comment: You can't derive from any `std` classes without using the standard library. You'll need to drop `-nostdlib`.

Comment: Don't forget that `std::streambuf` probably uses exceptions, at least indirectly.  (It will probably use `new`, which reports insufficient memory via an exception.)  So if you specify `-fno-exceptions`, you've pretty much made the use of `std::streambuf` impossible, regardless.

Comment: Drop -nostdlib, and probably -fno-exceptions, or drop the inheritance and write your own streambuf.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you able to use streams with exceptions off effectively, since IO error handling. And you probably will need an malloc. If you writing an OS kernel you need your memory manager first, for the kernel mode driver - use low-level OS functions like SLAB allocator for example.

One more thing - is C and C++ library. You need one if you'd like to use some functions from it. There were implementations like newlib, msullibc for the libc, and you will need to provide C++ ABI implementation and link with -lsupc++

Anyway if you are looking into an implementation you can look into https://github.com/incoder1/IO/blob/master/include/stream.hpp